# WordPress - Twenty Thirteen - Leave a Reply (comment) - can this be edited?

Tags: wordpress

I have a question regarding the `Leave a Repl`y section at the bottom of the `Twenty Thirteen` WordPress theme.  At the bottom of a page, you will see the area that asks for your Name, Email, Website, and then an option to write in a Comment.

I am wondering if it is possible to change the word *Website*, to *Agency*.  I looked in a couple files, but can't seem to find this area in the code.  I've looked in the `Comments.php`, as well as the `content.php` file.  At the bottom of the `content.php` file, I do see the area that I believe is the section that may need to be edited but unsure how to go about doing this.

Here is a screenshot of the area that I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: OF course it can be. Just search for the ID of that element and look for it in the WordPress editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Comments.php for the theme, replace the parameterless call to comment_form (at the bottom). You can pass in your modifications there. No need to modify the Core. See [comment_form API reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form).

Answer (score 3):

@user2898224:

The file you are looking for is the WordPress core file 'wp-includes\comment-template.php'.

You need to change line #2058, which looks like this:

```
'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label> ' .
```

All you have to do is change 'Website' to 'Agency' on this line.

Keep in mind that this change modifies a WordPress core file, so if you ever want to upgrade your WordPress installation, you will need to make the same change again after upgrading.

Modifiying WordPress core files is also not a very good idea, but in this case the change is small enough that you can get away with it.

**In the event that you do not want to modify (nor should you) a WordPress core file, you can also do the following:**

In the Twenty Thirteen theme's 'comments.php' file, replace this call to the comment_form function:

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

With this block of code (and yes, all of this code is necessary):

```
<?php           
    $fields = array(
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                        '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                        '<input id="email" name="email" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="email"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Agency' ) . '</label> ' .
                        '<input id="url" name="url" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="url"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
    );

    $comments_args = array(
        'fields' =>  $fields
    );

    comment_form( $comments_args );
?>
```

This may seem like a more complicated way to go about changing just one word on the comment form, but it will keep you from messing with any of the WordPress core files.

Comment: Wow such quick help.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I was in that area, and did see the 'Website' but was still a bit unsure on how it all worked.  But after reading everyones answers I see.  Also did not want to make changes to the files so this worked out perfect.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add or modify the comment form field by wordpress filter through functions.php of your theme.
Try to add this to your functions.php

```
function my_fields($fields) {
    // replace url with agency 
    $fields['url'] = '<p class="comment-form-agency"><label for="agency">' . __( 'Agency' ) . '</label> ' .
                     '<input id="agency" name="agency" type="text" value="" size="30" /></p>';
return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_fields');
```

or you can add agency input as new field

```
function my_fields($fields) {
        $fields['agency'] = '<p class="comment-form-agency"><label for="agency">' . __( 'Agency' ) . '</label> ' .
                         '<input id="agency" name="agency" type="text" value="" size="30" /></p>';
    return $fields;
    }
    add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_fields');
```